# Select most recent entry in table by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 SQL tables. `StudentTable`, `FeeAssociationTable` and `InvoiceTable`.
`StudentTable` has primary key of `AdmissionNumber`, `FeeAssociationTable` has primary key of `FeeAssociationID` and `InvioceTable` has primary key `InvoiceID`.

The `FeeAssociationTable` takes `AdmissionNumber` and assign a fee to it, then while depositing fee the `InvoiceTable` takes `AdmissionNumber` and calculate all his fee and subtract from paid and the inserts in the dues.

The problem is; same `AdmissionNumber`can have multiple row in InvoiceTable, **"How can I can select and sum all recent dues of each AdmissionNumber(not repeating)."**

Here is some data;

```
37  1   3000    January-2018    3000    0   2018-08-17
38  2   3000    January-2018    3000    0   2018-08-17
39  3   3000    January-2018    3000    0   2018-08-17
40  4   3000    January-2018    3000    0   2018-08-17
41  5   3000    January-2018    3000    0   2018-08-17
42  6   3000    January-2018    3000    0   2018-08-17
43  7   3000    January-2018    3000    0   2018-08-17
44  8   3000    January-2018    3000    0   2018-08-17
45  9   3000    January-2018    3000    0   2018-08-17
46  10  3000    January-2018    3000    0   2018-08-17
47  1   3200    June-2018   2500    700 2018-08-17
48  2   3200    June-2018   2500    700 2018-08-17
49  3   3200    June-2018   2500    700 2018-08-17
50  4   3200    June-2018   2500    700 2018-08-17
51  5   3200    June-2018   2500    700 2018-08-17
52  6   3200    June-2018   2500    700 2018-08-17
53  7   3200    June-2018   2500    700 2018-08-17
54  8   3200    June-2018   2500    700 2018-08-17
55  9   3200    June-2018   2500    700 2018-08-17
56  10  3200    June-2018   2500    700 2018-08-17
57  10  3700    July-2018   2500    1200    2018-08-17
58  9   3700    July-2018   2400    1300    2018-08-17
59  8   3700    July-2018   200 3500    2018-08-17
60  7   3700    July-2018   2000    1700    2018-08-17
61  1   3700    July-2018   1500    2200    2018-08-17
62  2   3700    July-2018   3100    600 2018-08-17
```

**Expectation:**
I want the most recent dues of each student without adding in the previous one.

For example:-

```
InvoiceId AdmissionNumber  TotalFee   Month         Paid   Dues     Date
    37       1                3000      January-2018    3000    0     2018-08-17
    47       1                3200      June-2018       2500   700    2018-08-17
    61       1                3700      July-2018       1500   2200   2018-08-17
```

There are 3 entries of `AdmissionNumber 1` in the InvoiceTable. In the first one there are no due, but in the second entry there are Dues of 700, and in the third the dues of 2200 on `AdmissionNumber 1`.

The thing I want to do is select last one which can be done by this code given below:

```
SELECT Dues FROM InvoiceTable AS IT
            WHERE IT.InvoiceID = (SELECT MAX(InvoiceID) 
            FROM InvoiceTable WHERE AdmissionNumber = 1)
```

This is for single I want list of recent dues of every student.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please don't post images of data, post it as `text`. The volunteers trying to help you won't be able to use an image of data to test, or write, a solution.

Comment: Also, when you update your post to replace the image with `text` could you also post what you've tried so far please? This is quite a common question on SO, so I *assume* you had a look at the questions that were presented to you that might be similar when you posted yours and tried some of the answers; perhaps they didn't work? Could you explain why they didn't work? Did you receive an error, or perhaps it didn't return the dataset you expected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you give an example of an expected output

Comment: Since "most recent entry" and "sum of all recent entries" sounds quite different in my ears, I can't see what either of them means. Could you please explain? And: Are fields on the image part of the `InvoiceTable`table?

Comment: I updated the post please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your follow up information, I believe the following will give you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  invoiceId, AdmissionNumber, Dues 
FROM InvoiceTable AS IT
WHERE IT.invoiceId IN (SELECT MAX(invoiceId)
                        FROM InvoiceTable
                        GROUP BY AdmissionNumber)
ORDER BY AdmissionNumber ASC
```

They query you tried in your example was close, it just had to be adapted to work for the whole table and not a single `AdmissionNumber`.

Here is a demo of this working: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f0757/1)

Comment: That would sum up all the entries of AdmissionNumber which I don't want

Comment: @Farhan I have updated my answer based on your revised question.